# Proving that $\int_0^1 x^{2n} \sin (\pi x) dx$ are polynomials of degree $2n$ in $\pi$, divided by $\pi^{2n+1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I think that the integrals $\int_0^1 x^{2n} \sin(\pi x)dx$ are polynomials of degree at most $2n$, with all expoents being even numbers, divided by $\pi^{2n+1}$

A few examples given by wolfram:

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 x^2\sin(\pi x) dx = \frac{\pi^2-4}{\pi^3}\\
&\int_0^1 x^4 \sin(\pi x) dx = \frac{48-12\pi^2+\pi^4}{\pi^5}\\
&\int_0^1 x^6\sin(\pi x) dx = \frac{-1440+360\pi^2-30\pi^4+\pi^6}{\pi^7}
\end{align}

How we prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** By integration by parts,
$$\int_0^1 x^{2n}\sin(\pi x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{2n}{\pi}\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\cos(\pi x)dx$$
and 
$$\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\cos(\pi x)dx=-\frac{2n-1}{\pi}\int_0^1 x^{2n-2}\sin(\pi x)dx$$

Comment: The last integral should have $x^{2n-2}$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Right, thanks for catching that!